# How to fix the "Name of the mongoose Model" is not a constructor in graphql when mutating

Tags: mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

Mutating data in the graphql playground says the message of 
Message: Student is not a constructor
Error: "TypeError: Student is not a constructor"
Student is my Mongoose Model.

I've tried reinstalling my node_modules, searching some fix on the github.

This is my Mutation Function

```
 addStudent: async (
      root,
      { studentId, firstName, lastName, email, password },
      { Student }
    ) => {
      const newStudent = await new Student({
        studentId,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password
      }).save();
      return newStudent;
    }
```

and this is my Mongoose Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const StudentSchema = new Schema({
  studentId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  // sectionId: {
  //   type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
  //   ref: "Section",
  //   nullable: true
  // },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", StudentSchema);
```

The student should be created, but that error pops up with that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I should have provided query variables rather than manual typing on the graphql mutation

Comment: I did not understand clearly can u give me an example or exact answer what you have changed

Answer (score 1):

Await working on promise but here you are passing student object
so it returns Student is not a constructor

```
const newStudent = await new Student({
        studentId,
        ....
      }).save();
```

Instead, you can do this

1) create student object using append

```
const newStudent = new Student({})
newStudent.studentId = studentId
newStudent.firstName = firstName
newStudent.lastName = lastName
newStudent.email = email
newStudent.password = password
```

2) Create student object using constructor

```
const newStudent = new Student({ 
    studentId,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password
})
```

and save using promise async and await

```
  await newStudent.save()
```

or

```
const newStudent = await Student.create({
    studentId,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you but those solutions aren't working, its the same error appeared.

Comment: You should use a dynamic variable instead of manual typing on the graphql mutation. Because you pass Student model in Mutation.