# How to fix constructor error in GraphQL Mutation with Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema

Having a lot of trouble with a GraphQL mutation Mongoose error for validating if a user is new or existing in MongoDB. Per the code below the error message is "message": "User is not a constructor".

A similar issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474130/how-to-fix-the-name-of-the-mongoose-model-is-not-a-constructor-in-graphql-when), and I redefined the variable below given each method in the solution to that linked issue with similar errors - only change in error was due to lacking constructor such as when I used other methods like append the error is "User is undefined".

CodeSandbox with all the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-server-sh19t?fontsize=14

The code in question is:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  joinDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  favorites: {
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    required: true,
    ref: "Post"
  }
});

// compile model
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

var getUserModel = function() {
  return mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
};

Mutation: {
    signupUser: async (_, { username, email, password }, { User }) => {
      let user = await getUserModel().findOne({ username });
      if (user) {
        throw new Error("Please choose another username");
      }
      const newUser = await new User({
        username,
        email,
        password
      }).save();
      return newUser;
    }
  }
};
```

The full error is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "User is not a constructor",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "signupUser"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: User is not a constructor",
            "    at signupUser (/xxx/xxx/xxx/servers.js:175:29)",
            "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "signupUser"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined",
            "    at signupUser (/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/servers.js:175:38)"
```

Any assistance to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's already a number of similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275169), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747721) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774997)) that boil down to the same root cause -- trying to use an undefined value as a constructor so I am closing this question as a dupe. You can see a more detailed explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That TypeError is thrown any time you try to use the `new` keyword with something that's not a constructing, including an undefined value. Even if you define a User variable outside of the constructor, you're still [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript) that variable because you're destructuring the context parameter and declaring a `User` variable that way. If you're not passing the `User` model to your context correctly, attempting to get the value from the context will result in the value being undefined. Either fix the context or don't unnecessarily destructure it.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote but thanks for the input.